# Excel, how to separate two numbers when they are divided with an enter?

Tags: excel

I have a cell that looks like this

```
"29
20170318455319"
```

I tried to separate it with  "text to columns"
but it doesn't work

the numbers are separated with an in cell enter

Comment: How "in cell enter"? Using ctrl + H, try replacing the "space" of "in cell enter" by (copying it and pasting the same in find) with a "normal" space with space bar. Then use the text to columns.

Comment: how do I replace it to 10000 cells at once   ?

Comment: Assuming it worked for one cell, select all the cells you want to replace, and do the above once.

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: Solved ,  I used text to columns and set a separator manually

Comment: Which separator did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a formula for first and second numbers respectively:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(CHAR(10),A1))
```

Here `CODE(10)` is so called line feed (LF) symbol.